# M-LVDS differential signals through multiplexers

Tags: usb, differential, multiplexer, transmission-line, lvds

I'm experimenting with M-LVDS via USB 3.1 cables, passing the differential signals through the SuperSpeed lanes. I'm using the DS91M040 for driving M-LVDS. So far no issues, however, I need now to work with multiplexers for switching the signals according to the position of the USB-C cable (which is detected via CC1 and CC2).

If I use multiplexers, how drastically will they affect these signals (e.g., impedance and signal quality)? Could they break the physical line? I will have multiple end-points in series and a termination on the last one.

Are there dedicated chips for this? Would an analog switch work (e.g. 4016)?
TI makes USB controllers that include multiplexers for these signals, like the TPS65987D and TPS65988. Could I use one of these chips?

Any clarifications on this subject will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What speeds you require? Why are you using standard cables for non-standard custom purposes? If USB3.1 speeds go up to 10 Gbps, these muxes should work slower signals as well, but usually the wires are AC coupled between devices so may not work with DC coupled signals.

Comment: The max speed I'm using is about 12Mbps. USB allows alternate mode for different protocols, so I'm experimenting with some ideas.